# Oracle hierarchical query - two paths merged into one at the end

Tags: sql, oracle

Create the schema at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c889/3):

I would like to query a hierarchy table with schema in Oracle. Schema and sample data as following:

```
CREATE TABLE mappings 
(
    from_name varchar(20),
    to_name varchar(20),
    start_date date
);

INSERT INTO mappings VALUES ('node 1', 'node 1-2', date'2023-1-1');
INSERT INTO mappings VALUES ('node 1-2', 'node 1-3', date'2023-2-1');
INSERT INTO mappings VALUES ('node 1-3', 'Final Node 1', date'2023-3-1');
INSERT INTO mappings VALUES ('node 2', 'Final Node 2', date'2023-1-15');
INSERT INTO mappings VALUES ('node 3', 'Node 3-1', date'2023-2-1');
INSERT INTO mappings VALUES ('node 3-1', 'Final Node 1', date'2023-2-15');
```

The data represents 3 different mapping paths with time periods:

- Path 1: Node 1 -> Node 1-2 -> Node 1-3 -> Final Node1
- Path 2: Node 2 -> Final Node 2
- Path 3: Node 3 -> Node 3-1 -> Final Node1

Please note that the path 1 and path 3 merge at the end

The output I would like to generate is:

| From | To | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| node 1 | Final Node 1 | 2023-1-1 | 2023-1-31 |
| node 1-2 | Final Node 1 | 2023-2-1 | 2023-2-28 |
| node 1-3 | Final Node 1 | 2023-3-1 |  |
| node 2 | Final Node 2 | 2023-1-15 |  |
| node 3-1 | Final Node 1 | 2023-2-1 | 2023-2-14 |
| node 3-2 | Final Node 1 | 2023-2-15 |  |

My code in Oracle:

```
WITH map AS 
(
    SELECT 
       connect_by_root(from_name) AS begin_node,
       (to_name) AS end_node,
       connect_by_root(start_date) AS start_date,
       LEVEL
   FROM 
       mappings
   WHERE 
       connect_by_isleaf = 1 
   CONNECT BY nocycle from_name = PRIOR to_name
)
SELECT 
    m.begin_node,
    m.end_node,
    start_date,
    LEAD(start_date - 1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY end_node ORDER BY start_date) AS end_date
FROM 
    map m
```

Above code seems working in the most of cases, but the end_date is not correct in some of cases. It picks up the wrong ending date from another path since the path 1 and path 3 merges at the end.

Comment: Your data contains a typo. The penultimate `INSERT` should have a lower-case `n` like this `INSERT INTO mappings VALUES ('node 3', 'node 3-1', date'2023-2-1');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the map in the reverse direction first to find the root node and then generate the map to the leaves and when you want to find the `end_date` you can `PARTITION BY` the root node (rather than the end node):

```sql
WITH reverse_map (from_name, to_name, start_date, root_name) AS (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT from_name,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT to_name,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT start_date,
         from_name
  FROM   mappings
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR from_name = to_name
)
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT from_name AS begin_node,
       to_name AS end_node,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT start_date AS start_date,
       LEAD(CONNECT_BY_ROOT start_date) OVER (
         PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT root_name
         ORDER BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT start_date
       ) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS end_date
FROM   reverse_map
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       from_name = PRIOR to_name
```

Which outputs:

| BEGIN_NODE | END_NODE | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| node 1 | Final Node 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-31 23:59:59 |
| node 1-2 | Final Node 1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-02-28 23:59:59 |
| node 1-3 | Final Node 1 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| node 2 | Final Node 2 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | *null* |
| node 3 | Final Node 1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-02-14 23:59:59 |
| node 3-1 | Final Node 1 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pOqMjMzE)